# .sln file contains information in xml or in code (like vb)?

Tags: asp.net

I am reading **Developing Web Applications with .net frame work 4.0** book (70-515). In that I found one sentence that at page number 21 **A solution file is an XML file that contains information...** After I read this sentence I opened the .sln file in note pad. But strangely I didn't find any xml over there. It contains some code which is some what similar to VB code. Even I referred to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) link, there are no mentioning it is xml file. Is that sentence is wrong in that book? Please any one clarify me!

Answer (score 2):

The project files are XML, however the solution files are not.

Comment: My *project* files are XML, however.

Comment: But if you refer the link what I provided, the microsoft didn't said that. They shown up some of the sample solution files, no sample contains xml. Am I wrong?

Comment: It looks like the book is wrong, I went back and checked and project files are XML but solution files are not.

Comment: But you said that earlier solution files are indeed xml files!!

Comment: @Mihir seems my memory isn't 100% perfect.